# how to turn an java application into REST?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, web

i'm trying to use REST in other application that i have already build and i have some questions.

The application is a Java application that gets information(int and strings) from a server.
I have found Jersey framework and i'm trying to integrate to the application.

---

**the structure of the application is:**

```
->start main()
-> get information()
-> print information()
... and other methods... but for now, just to understand.. just leave it simple...
```

Now i would like to have...

```
->start main()
-> get information()
-> send information() - I now that must be put() a different server
```

---

**architecture**

```
win server <-> Java application -> http Server
```

---

**questions**
1 - Can i use REST inside the Java application or have to rebuild in order to support REST?

2 - Can i use REST without any server (ex:tomcat). hoW?

Comment: Have a look on JAX-RS Spec. You can create a standalone server serving REST requests

Comment: Have a look at [Dropwizard](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/) for development complete REST application in java.

Comment: Here is a link that might be useful. http://www.java-forums.org/blogs/web-service/1145-how-create-java-web-service.html

Comment: Priyesh can it be done with jersey?

Answer (score 0):

Please find answers below of your questions

Q) Can i use REST inside the Java application or have to rebuild in order to support REST?

Ans) - A RESTful web service exposes a set of resources(it can be your java methods) that identify the targets of the interaction with its clients. Resources are identified by URIs, which provide a global addressing space for resource and service discovery

Your methods will be acting as a resources and URL will be linked to those resources to expose them. 
You need not rebuild again your java application
I exposed resource in my spring-ioc application using Apache cxf.

```
@WebService(serviceName = "vertragServices")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public interface VertragService {

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public abstract @ResponseBody VertragList getRequirementList();

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/{id}")
    public abstract Vertrag getRequirement(@PathParam("id") long id);


    @PUT
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN) 
    public @ResponseBody String updateRequirement (Requirement requirement);
}
```

Q) - Can i use REST without any server (ex:tomcat). hoW?

Ans)- Representational State Transfer (REST) is an architectural style that specifies constraints, such as the uniform interface, that if applied to a web service induce desirable properties. It applies to web application only and have to applied to web service for which you require a server.
Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gijqy.html

Comment: thanks, let me understand...
I have create a web service, i can get and post information.. this is working... (simple example)... how do i put my main app to execute?

in my app.. i have main to start.. then the rest of the code.. now how can i execute the main in the web service?  threads?

Comment: You don't require main in web application.
And the function which you were calling through main, now you are going to call those mehtods(i.e., resources) using URL's. And every URL will be passed through servlet written in web.xml.
So servlet will redirect your request to mapped method and method will be called. Either you can take Apache cxf provided servlet or Jersey provided Servlet.

Comment: i'm reading jersey framework. my problem is.. e need to add a process at the start of the program.  when i start the tomcat i would like to start my main program as well. The logic is.. main program capture data from a file an sends to other server by post using REST full. I can make the post part, i can't get the program to start...

Comment: Can u explain more what and where you have written main program...?

Comment: found it - http://crunchify.com/create-very-simple-jersey-rest-service-and-send-json-data-from-java-client/ 

thanks any way :D